# Node voltages in supernode analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic diagram]

(Image source - Edited from Figure 3 of "[SUPERNODE Circuit Analysis | Step by Step with Solved Example](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2015/02/supernode-circuit-analysis-step-by-step-solved-example.html)")

In the given image why aren't the node voltages of nodes marked 1 and 2 same? There isn't any component between them and they are connected by a wire so shouldn't they be at the same potential?

Comment: That website is semi-insane. In any case, a supernode solution would look like: \$6\cdot V_3+2\cdot\left(V_3+5\right)=13\quad\therefore\:V_3=\frac{3}{8}\:\text{V}=375\:\text{mV}\$. Without using supernodes, it's two equations in two unknowns and the solution is still the same for \$V_3\$.

Answer (score 1):

They are at the same potential, and for the purposes of circuit theory they are the same node --- they should not be labelled with two different node names.

Comment: The answer given is node voltage of 1 is 1.708 V and node voltage of 2 is 5.375 V

Comment: Are you sure that answer goes with this diagram? Because there are only 2 nodes (other than ground) in this diagram, and they must have 5 V difference between them.

Comment: Yes, i can provide the link for the same.

Comment: https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2015/02/supernode-circuit-analysis-step-by-step-solved-example.html

Comment: It looks like that's just a terrible website. Eq 1 makes no sense at all (where do the factors of 3 in the numerators come from? Why are they dividing by 0?) Why are they resolving division by 0 by setting those terms to 0? Whoever wrote it was very confused.